# CUDA memory access pattern in 2D

Tags: caching, cuda, gpu

I coded a simple kernel, to test the memory access pattern:

```cpp
__global__ void kernel_A(float *g_data, int dimx, int dimy, int niterations) {
    for (int iy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; iy < dimy; iy += blockDim.y * gridDim.y) {
        for (int ix = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; ix < dimx; ix += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
            int idx = iy * dimx + ix;

            float value = g_data[idx];

            for (int i = 0; i < niterations; i++) {
                value += __fsqrt_rn(__logf(value) + 1.f);
            }
            g_data[idx] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

First I launch it with 1d block and 1d grid:

```cpp
void launchKernel(float * d_data, int dimx, int dimy, int niterations) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
    int num_sms = prop.multiProcessorCount;

    int num_threads = 128;
    int num_blocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(&num_blocks, kernel_A, num_threads, 0);
    num_blocks *= num_sms;

    dim3 block(num_threads);
    dim3 grid(num_blocks);
    kernel_A<<<grid, block>>>(d_data, dimx, dimy, niterations);
}
```

I also do another launch, with 2d grid:

```cpp
void launchKernel(float * d_data, int dimx, int dimy, int niterations) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
    int num_sms = prop.multiProcessorCount;

    int num_threads = 128;
    int num_blocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(&num_blocks, kernel_A, num_threads, 0);
    num_blocks *= num_sms;

    dim3 block(num_threads);
    dim3 grid(1, num_blocks);
    kernel_A<<<grid, block>>>(d_data, dimx, dimy, niterations);
}
```

Then I run this benchmark on RTX 4090, where the `dimx` and `dimy` are both `8*1024`, same `niterations=5`, but I got quite different results:

- launch 1 uses 4.22 ms
- launch 2 uses 0.67 ms

I don't understand, because from the memory access pattern, all threads are good, and each element will be read/write only once, so I don't think GPU L2 cache will benefit a lot. If I understand correct, L2 cache read one cache line, which each thread will use more than one transaction to get the data from global memory, I don't see the benefit of spatial locality.

Comment: Are you restarting the application between tests of these two launch configurations? Otherwise you could fall prey to lazy loading and other initialization effects. Try swapping the order to see if it has an effect. Other than that locality of data can be relevant for TLB efficiency. Does Nvidia [Nsight Compute](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-compute) indicate anything?

Comment: @Homer512 , thanks, no matter which order I run them, performance doesn't change. I am also trying to setup a machine in AWS (cause I don't have GPU by hand), and only AWS can get GPU metrics, will see what I get once I have that setup.

Comment: @Homer512 I actually don't have code to test both, so I build launch 1 and run the benchmark, then I modify the launch code, just change the grid size shape, then build and launch it. So I never run two launch in one process. And I've tested this on different GPUs, same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is due to very different GPU utilization in each case.

Lets see if we can get a better understanding of what your code is doing by calculating all relevant data (then we can think through it carefully).

In your first launch ("1D" grid), `iy` starts out at zero for all threads, and the grid stride in `y` is 1. Therefore the outer loop iterates `dimy` times.  On a `sm_89` device, on CUDA 12.2, the max blocks occupancy API returns 12 for me, which makes sense.  12x128 = 1536, the maximum possible threads on a `sm_89` SM.  Your RTX 4090 has 128 SMs.  So your total blocks launched is 12x128, or 1536 blocks.  The total number of threads in that case is 1536x128 = 196,608.  This effectively is the grid width in `x` for the first launch.  The grid width in `y`, as we have already discovered, is 1.

So how will your 2D grid-stride loop in the kernel behave?

On the first iteration in `iy` loop, you will have 196,608 threads in `x`, but you only need 8x1024=8192 threads to cover the dataset width.  So of your 196,608 launched threads, only 8192 will do any useful work for that iteration of `iy`, and the remainder will simply hit the `ix<dimx` test and do nothing.  That doesn't sound like a sensible use of resources.

Of course this same behavior manifests on every iteration of `iy`: 8192 threads do something useful, the others don't.  So if we naively applied that to the GPU (since you have sized your grid to match the GPU), then we could say that we are using 8192/196,608 of the GPU in a useful fashion, ie. we are using ~4.2% of the GPU available capability.

Sure, you might say, but doesn't the grid stride loop help there?  Don't those non-useful blocks just iterate quickly through the `iy` extent, and retire?  Yes, they do, but they leave behind empty space on the GPU.  The work that could be done in the actual dataset does not get scheduled, because it is already assigned to other already scheduled threads/blocks.  So you really have assigned just 4.2% of the thread capacity of your GPU to work on the problem.

In the second launch case ("2D" grid), the situation is different.  The "patch" that a single grid stride works on is not entirely linear in x.  It is a two dimensional patch, consisting of threads in `x` (128), and blocks in `y` (1536). I'm not going to work through all the same arithmetic, but this different shape "patch" means that in many/most iterations of your grid stride, the entire grid (all threads) are doing useful work.  So your GPU utilization is much higher in this case.

If this treatment is valid, then we should observe a significant difference in average SM utilization.  I don't have a RTX4090 to work on, but I do have a `sm_89` device, an L4 GPU, with 58 SMs.  So it still has the "mismatched" shape issue, but not quite as extreme as your RTX4090 with 128 SMs.

[Nsight compute](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-nsight-compute-to-inspect-your-kernels/) in [the SOL section](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHN5fpfu8As) includes a measurement of SM utilization, called "Compute (SM) Throughput" in the CLI output.   Here is what it looks like running your code on my L4 GPU with 58 SMs:

```
# cat t139.cu
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#define USECPSEC 1000000ULL

unsigned long long dtime_usec(unsigned long long start=0){

  timeval tv;
  gettimeofday(&tv, 0);
  return ((tv.tv_sec*USECPSEC)+tv.tv_usec)-start;
}

__global__ void kernel_A(float *g_data, int dimx, int dimy, int niterations) {
    for (int iy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; iy < dimy; iy += blockDim.y * gridDim.y) {
        for (int ix = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; ix < dimx; ix += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) {
            int idx = iy * dimx + ix;

            float value = g_data[idx];

            for (int i = 0; i < niterations; i++) {
                value += __fsqrt_rn(__logf(value) + 1.f);
            }
            g_data[idx] = value;
        }
    }
}

void launchKernel(float * d_data, int dimx, int dimy, int niterations, int type=0) {
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, 0);
    int num_sms = prop.multiProcessorCount;

    int num_threads = 128;
    int num_blocks;
    cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor(&num_blocks, kernel_A, num_threads, 0);
    num_blocks *= num_sms;
    std::cout << "num blocks: " << num_blocks << std::endl;
    dim3 block(num_threads);
    dim3 grid;
    if (type)
      grid=dim3(1,num_blocks);
    else
      grid=dim3(num_blocks);
    kernel_A<<<grid, block>>>(d_data, dimx, dimy, niterations);
}

int main(){

  int niterations=5;
  int dimx=8*1024;
  int dimy=8*1024;
  float *d_data;
  cudaMalloc(&d_data, sizeof(*d_data)*dimx*dimy);
  launchKernel(d_data, dimx, dimy, niterations, 0);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  unsigned long long dt = dtime_usec(0);
  launchKernel(d_data, dimx, dimy, niterations, 0);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  std::cout << "elapsed 0: " << dt/(float)USECPSEC << "s" << std::endl;
  dt = dtime_usec(0);
  launchKernel(d_data, dimx, dimy, niterations, 1);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  dt = dtime_usec(dt);
  std::cout << "elapsed 1: " << dt/(float)USECPSEC << "s" << std::endl;
}

# nvcc -o t139 t139.cu -arch=sm_89
# ncu ./t139
==PROF== Connected to process 137887 (/root/bobc/t139)
num blocks: 696
==PROF== Profiling "kernel_A" - 0: 0%....50%....100% - 9 passes
num blocks: 696
==PROF== Profiling "kernel_A" - 1: 0%....50%....100% - 9 passes
elapsed 0: 0.478202s
num blocks: 696
==PROF== Profiling "kernel_A" - 2: 0%....50%....100% - 9 passes
elapsed 1: 0.342003s
==PROF== Disconnected from process 137887
[137887] t139@127.0.0.1
  kernel_A(float *, int, int, int) (696, 1, 1)x(128, 1, 1), Context 1, Stream 7, Device 0, CC 8.9
    Section: GPU Speed Of Light Throughput
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------
    Metric Name               Metric Unit Metric Value
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------
    DRAM Frequency          cycle/nsecond         6.25
    SM Frequency            cycle/usecond       827.17
    Elapsed Cycles                  cycle   14,037,832
    Memory Throughput                   %        12.69
    DRAM Throughput                     %        12.69
    Duration                      msecond        16.77
    L1/TEX Cache Throughput             %         3.07
    L2 Cache Throughput                 %         3.12
    SM Active Cycles                cycle 5,878,996.60
    Compute (SM) Throughput             %        17.66
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------

    OPT   This kernel exhibits low compute throughput and memory bandwidth utilization relative to the peak performance
          of this device. Achieved compute throughput and/or memory bandwidth below 60.0% of peak typically indicate
          latency issues. Look at Scheduler Statistics and Warp State Statistics for potential reasons.

    Section: Launch Statistics
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
    Metric Name                          Metric Unit    Metric Value
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
    Block Size                                                   128
    Function Cache Configuration                     CachePreferNone
    Grid Size                                                    696
    Registers Per Thread             register/thread              22
    Shared Memory Configuration Size           Kbyte           32.77
    Driver Shared Memory Per Block       Kbyte/block            1.02
    Dynamic Shared Memory Per Block       byte/block               0
    Static Shared Memory Per Block        byte/block               0
    Threads                                   thread          89,088
    Waves Per SM                                                   1
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------

    Section: Occupancy
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Metric Name                     Metric Unit Metric Value
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Block Limit SM                        block           24
    Block Limit Registers                 block           21
    Block Limit Shared Mem                block           32
    Block Limit Warps                     block           12
    Theoretical Active Warps per SM        warp           48
    Theoretical Occupancy                     %          100
    Achieved Occupancy                        %        35.36
    Achieved Active Warps Per SM           warp        16.97
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------

    OPT   Estimated Speedup: 64.64%
          This kernel's theoretical occupancy is not impacted by any block limit. The difference between calculated
          theoretical (100.0%) and measured achieved occupancy (35.4%) can be the result of warp scheduling overheads
          or workload imbalances during the kernel execution. Load imbalances can occur between warps within a block
          as well as across blocks of the same kernel. See the CUDA Best Practices Guide
          (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#occupancy) for more details on
          optimizing occupancy.

  kernel_A(float *, int, int, int) (696, 1, 1)x(128, 1, 1), Context 1, Stream 7, Device 0, CC 8.9
    Section: GPU Speed Of Light Throughput
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------
    Metric Name               Metric Unit Metric Value
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------
    DRAM Frequency          cycle/nsecond         6.15
    SM Frequency            cycle/usecond       798.00
    Elapsed Cycles                  cycle   14,171,756
    Memory Throughput                   %        12.32
    DRAM Throughput                     %        12.32
    Duration                      msecond        17.54
    L1/TEX Cache Throughput             %         3.05
    L2 Cache Throughput                 %         3.08
    SM Active Cycles                cycle 5,926,135.90
    Compute (SM) Throughput             %        17.69
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------

    OPT   This kernel exhibits low compute throughput and memory bandwidth utilization relative to the peak performance
          of this device. Achieved compute throughput and/or memory bandwidth below 60.0% of peak typically indicate
          latency issues. Look at Scheduler Statistics and Warp State Statistics for potential reasons.

    Section: Launch Statistics
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
    Metric Name                          Metric Unit    Metric Value
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
    Block Size                                                   128
    Function Cache Configuration                     CachePreferNone
    Grid Size                                                    696
    Registers Per Thread             register/thread              22
    Shared Memory Configuration Size           Kbyte           32.77
    Driver Shared Memory Per Block       Kbyte/block            1.02
    Dynamic Shared Memory Per Block       byte/block               0
    Static Shared Memory Per Block        byte/block               0
    Threads                                   thread          89,088
    Waves Per SM                                                   1
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------

    Section: Occupancy
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Metric Name                     Metric Unit Metric Value
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Block Limit SM                        block           24
    Block Limit Registers                 block           21
    Block Limit Shared Mem                block           32
    Block Limit Warps                     block           12
    Theoretical Active Warps per SM        warp           48
    Theoretical Occupancy                     %          100
    Achieved Occupancy                        %        35.28
    Achieved Active Warps Per SM           warp        16.93
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------

    OPT   Estimated Speedup: 64.72%
          This kernel's theoretical occupancy is not impacted by any block limit. The difference between calculated
          theoretical (100.0%) and measured achieved occupancy (35.3%) can be the result of warp scheduling overheads
          or workload imbalances during the kernel execution. Load imbalances can occur between warps within a block
          as well as across blocks of the same kernel. See the CUDA Best Practices Guide
          (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#occupancy) for more details on
          optimizing occupancy.

  kernel_A(float *, int, int, int) (1, 696, 1)x(128, 1, 1), Context 1, Stream 7, Device 0, CC 8.9
    Section: GPU Speed Of Light Throughput
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------
    Metric Name               Metric Unit Metric Value
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------
    DRAM Frequency          cycle/nsecond         6.24
    SM Frequency            cycle/usecond       806.90
    Elapsed Cycles                  cycle    2,160,446
    Memory Throughput                   %        79.10
    DRAM Throughput                     %        79.10
    Duration                      msecond         2.64
    L1/TEX Cache Throughput             %        16.89
    L2 Cache Throughput                 %        20.03
    SM Active Cycles                cycle 2,083,805.60
    Compute (SM) Throughput             %        74.22
    ----------------------- ------------- ------------

    INF   Compute and Memory are well-balanced: To reduce runtime, both computation and memory traffic must be reduced.
          Check both the Compute Workload Analysis and Memory Workload Analysis sections.

    Section: Launch Statistics
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
    Metric Name                          Metric Unit    Metric Value
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------
    Block Size                                                   128
    Function Cache Configuration                     CachePreferNone
    Grid Size                                                    696
    Registers Per Thread             register/thread              22
    Shared Memory Configuration Size           Kbyte           32.77
    Driver Shared Memory Per Block       Kbyte/block            1.02
    Dynamic Shared Memory Per Block       byte/block               0
    Static Shared Memory Per Block        byte/block               0
    Threads                                   thread          89,088
    Waves Per SM                                                   1
    -------------------------------- --------------- ---------------

    Section: Occupancy
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Metric Name                     Metric Unit Metric Value
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------
    Block Limit SM                        block           24
    Block Limit Registers                 block           21
    Block Limit Shared Mem                block           32
    Block Limit Warps                     block           12
    Theoretical Active Warps per SM        warp           48
    Theoretical Occupancy                     %          100
    Achieved Occupancy                        %        90.75
    Achieved Active Warps Per SM           warp        43.56
    ------------------------------- ----------- ------------

    INF   This kernel's theoretical occupancy is not impacted by any block limit.

#
```

We see that in the first and second launch, both of which I am issuing as "type 0", ie. your "1D" case, the SM throughput is about 17%.  In the 3rd launch, which is my "type 1" corresponding to your "2D" case, the SM throughput is about 75%.  Furthermore the Nsight compute "rules" or expert system output in the 1D case mentions the following:

> This kernel exhibits low compute throughput and memory bandwidth utilization relative to the peak performance of this device.

The low compute throughput is directly related to the "Compute (SM) Throughput" measurement. That notation is not given in the 2D case, and instead it states:

> Compute and Memory are well-balanced:

My L4 GPU only has 58 SMs compared to your 128, so the shape mismatch issue while severe, is not quite as bad as on your RTX 4090.  I would expect the above comparison to be even worse (the "1D" case probably has even lower SM throughput) on your RTX 4090.

Comment: Thanks a lot, how stupid I was :) yes, in 1d, there are too many threads working on one row, and many threads become idle!!

Comment: I don't think its stupid.  When I am teaching CUDA I often suggest that a grid-stride loop is a nice way to decouple the grid sizing from the problem dimensions.  At least in the 1D grid stride loop case, there aren't really any problems you're likely to run into, especially if you do grid sizing the way you have done here (by querying the GPU).  However, your test case shows that in the 2D grid-stride loop case, there are potential issues that need to be considered, and we can't just assume that the grid stride pattern will always work nicely.

Comment: Also thanks for showing the profiling usage, I was setting up AWS EC2 to be able to run nsight